# Using a custom image for MarkerCluster

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a specific image i'd like to use for the MarkerCluster icon:

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
  });

Simply replacing the url with the path to my image doesn't work.. It just shows the number of markers that will show if you zoom in.. How do you use a custom image?

Comment: Sounds like the URL you are providing isn't working.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.